# Communicating with Mifare Plus

Tags: smartcard, mifare

I am new to the smart card world. I would like to ask one question.
I have a Mifare Plus card, and I want to "communicate" with it somehow
(e.g., send commands etc.). What are the available SDKs for it? 
(Preferable language: C/C++ although some other languages could also be ok).
I also have a reader.

Comment: Which reader you are using...

Comment: the reader is omnikey

Comment: Look at the edit part of my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a library named "Winscard".you should use it.

Win32 API for communicating with smartcards within Windows platform in form SCardXXX.Similar implementation for Linux is developed under
Muscle project as PC/SC Lite API. We will work with
in Windows platform.
Following functions will be used:

- SCardEstablishContext
- SCardListReaders
- SCardConnect
- SCardReconnect
- SCardDisconnect
- SCardReleaseContext
- SCardTransmit

**EDIT:**

Read this document [Omnikey_Contactless_developer_Guide](http://www.hidglobal.com/sites/hidglobal.com/files/omnikey_contactless_developer_guide.pdf)

Comment: hey vikky, so you are referring to the SCard API right? do you  have link for it? This one I found: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd627646(v=vs.85).aspx - says "topic is not current" and links to some Minidriver specification ..

Comment: You can use Winscard Library for communication and send APDUs

Comment: if I follow the instructions mentioned in the developer guide document you mentioned, and write the code for communicating with the reader/smart card using that API -- does it mean that ANY reader will be able to communicate with our smart card? or only omnikey readers?

Comment: I am not sure.....But I think it will be work only for omnikey reader...(Correct me If I am wrong)

Comment: I think If you use Winscard.dll...then the only PCSC complianmt reader will be communicate through....Reader list is here http://www.pcscworkgroup.com/compatibleproducts/CompatibleProducts-rev090110.pdf

Comment: @ vikky: yes I think if I use Win 32 APi methods like  SCardEstablishContext it should work with many readers? the list you showed shows many readers? Also vikky as I am beginner in this area, how many programs does one usually write to make smart card reader system work, e.g., one program for smart card, one program for reader? where do these programs reside?

Comment: @user2568508....Sorry I am not getting your point...If you want any discussion, you can mail me....

Comment: can you give me your mail address, I will write a short mail and briefly explain my question

Comment: Could you please check my new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18740868/communicating-with-mifare-plus-with-win-32-api? thanks.